# Durandal modal cannot find view

Tags: durandal

I have a modal dialog called from a button.  All seems to work fine, except I have to put the cancelconfirm.html in the viewmodels directory with the cancelconfirm.js file or it cannot find the html file.  It is looking in the viewmodels directory for it.

I think it is the way I'm calling showModal(), but I was thinking that since I have it in my router durandal would know where to look for the view?

```
app.showModal('areas/share/viewmodels/cancelconfirm')
```

Just starting durandal, what am I missing?

Thanks

here is my code setting up the viewLocator and app root

```
    viewLocator.useConvention('../../areas/share/viewmodels', '../../areas/share/views', '../../areas/share/views');

        // show the app start view model
        app.setRoot('../../areas/share/viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');


    define(function() {
    var app = require('durandal/app');
    var logger = require('logger/logger');
    var router = require('durandal/plugins/router');


    function Share(email, downloadProxy, downloadMaster, comment, alertUser) {
        this.email = email;
        this.downloadProxy = ko.observable(downloadProxy);
        this.downloadMaster = ko.observable(downloadMaster);
        this.comment = ko.observable(comment);
        this.alertUser = ko.observable(alertUser);
    }

    var shares = ko.observableArray();  // change this variable to recipients
    var shareId = ko.observable();
    var emailValidator = $("#email").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");    

    var addRecipient = function() {
        emailValidator = $("#email").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

        if (emailValidator.validate()) {


            logger.log("valid email address", "", "adding to share", false);
            var newShare = new Share(email.value, false, false, false, false);
            shares.push(newShare);
            emailValidator.hideMessages();                      
        }
    };

    function resetEmail() {   
        email.value = "";
        emailValidator.hideMessages();       
    }    

    var selectAll = function(share, event) {
         logger.log(share, "", "select all", false);
         if (event.currentTarget.checked == true) {
             share.downloadProxy(true);
             share.downloadMaster(true);
             share.comment(true);
             share.alertUser(true);
         } else {
             share.downloadProxy(false);
             share.downloadMaster(false);
             share.comment(false);
             share.alertUser(false);
         }

         return true;
     };

    var next = function() {
        router.navigateTo("#/share/" + shareId + "/settings");
    };

    var previous = function() {
        router.navigateTo("#/share/" + shareId + "/files");
    };

    var cancel = function() {
        app.showModal('areas/share/viewmodels/cancelconfirm').then(function(dialogResult){
            // add the storing of the user pref dontShow later
            // cookie or true preference?
            if(dialogResult.answer == 'Yes') {
                window.location.assign("asset");                                
            }
        });
    };      

    return {        
        shares : shares,
        addRecipient : addRecipient,
        selectAll : selectAll,
        resetEmail : resetEmail,        
        next : next,
        previous : previous,
        cancel : cancel,
        activate : function(context) {
            //app.showMessage("Share ==> " + shares()[0].email);
            shareId = context.id;
        }
    };
});
```

The requires are working now with the approach you suggested:

Still it is looking for the view file in the viewmodels directory.
Uncaught Error: /SkyTrack/resources/areas/share/viewmodels/cancelconfirm.html HTTP status: 404

Here is what I have in my main.js for require config:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/SkyTrack/resources/",
paths: {
    text: 'core/durandal/amd/text',
    durandal: "core/durandal",
    logger: "core/services",
    cancelconfirm: "areas/share/viewmodels"         
    }
});
```

The define block at the top of the file that calls the modal:
    define(function() { 
        var app = require('durandal/app');
        var logger = require('logger/logger');
        var router = require('durandal/plugins/router');
        var cancelconfirm = require('cancelconfirm/cancelconfirm');

The function that calls the modal

```
   var cancel = function() {        
        app.showModal(cancelconfirm).then(function(dialogResult){               
            // add the storing of the user pref dontShow later
            // cookie or true preference?
            if(dialogResult.answer == 'Yes') {
                window.location.assign("asset");                                
            }
        });
    };
```

I also had to add the require at the top of my shell.js 
(I don't quite get why, but until I did I was getting the "has not been loaded yet for context: _."
error)

Here is the complete content of shell.js:

```
define(function (require) {
    var router = require('durandal/plugins/router');
    var logger = require('logger/logger');
    var cancelconfirm = require('cancelconfirm/cancelconfirm');    

    return {
        router : router,
        activate : function () {
            logger.log("shell init activate share", "", "share shell", false);

            //router.mapNav("addshare");
            router.mapNav("files");
            router.mapNav("recipients");
            router.mapNav("settings");
            router.mapNav('cancelconfirm');            

            //allows regular links to work (so you can navigate between multiple SPA's)
            Sammy.Application.prototype.disable_push_state = true;
            return router.activate('files');
        }
    };
});
```

******************* Listing of main.js

```
require.config({
      baseUrl: "/SkyTrack/resources/",
    paths: {
        text: 'core/durandal/amd/text',
        durandal: "core/durandal",
        logger: "core/services",
        cancelconfirm: "areas/share/viewmodels/cancelconfirm"           
    }
});


define(function (require) {
    var app = require('durandal/app'),
    viewLocator = require('durandal/viewLocator'),
    viewModelBinder = require('durandal/viewModelBinder'),
    system = require('durandal/system'),
    router = require('durandal/plugins/router'),
    logger = require('logger/logger');

    system.debug(true);

    logger.log("using durandal", "", "main", false);
    app.title = "Share My Assets";

    app.start().then(function () {

        // kendo configuration 
        // Configure kendo data binding attribute prefix
        kendo.ns = "kendo-";
        logger.log("Configured kendo data binding prefix = 'data-kendo-*'", "", "main", false);

        // Add Durandal beforeBind event handler that will apply
        // Kendo data binding every time a viewModel is bound to a view
        viewModelBinder.beforeBind = function (viewModel, view) {
        logger.log("Applying Kendo data binding", "", "viewModelBinder", false);

            // Find all Kendo templates and add to the DOM before
            // bind is called
            var templates = $("script[type='text/x-kendo-template']", view);
            templates.each(function(i,item){
                $(document.body).append(item);
            });

            try
            {
                if(viewModel.kendoViewModelPropertyName != null)
                {
                    kendo.bind(view, viewModel[viewModel.kendoViewModelPropertyName]);
                }
                else
                {
                    kendo.bind(view, viewModel);
                }
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                logger.log("Error applying kendo MVVM bindings: " + e.message);
            }

        };



        // configure routing
        router.useConvention('../../areas/share/viewmodels');
        viewLocator.useConvention('../../areas/share/viewmodels', '../../areas/share/views', '../../areas/share/views');

        app.adaptToDevice();

        // show the app start view model
        app.setRoot('../../areas/share/viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
    });

});
```

Comment: Any reason your call to `app.showModal` is not just: `app.showModal('cancelConfirm')'?  Since you're setting up your conventions, there shouldn't be any need to specify the specific location of the view/model in the showModal.

Comment: When I change it to app.showModal("cancelconfirm")   it tries to locate the viewmodel in the baseUrl configured in my main.js and doesn't seem to be using the convention settings

Comment: Where is your useConvention call located?

Comment: in main.js in the then after app.start()   I have three other views that work just fine, and are using the conventions, however, they are not modals.  In debug I can see that cancelconfirm is in my visibleRoutes, and if I navigate to it using router.navigateTo everything is found and displayed, of course not in a modal, which is what I am after.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach instead:

```
var cancelconfirm = require('cancelconfirm');
app.showModal(cancelconfirm);
```

With this approach you're loading the view model in and passing that to the `showModal` call.  The `showModal` will then use the `viewLocator` to locate the view that is associated with the view model.  This way, you're not relying so much on durandal to find the appropriate view model, but instead allowing requirejs to load the module for you and the letting durandal locate the view.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Module name "cancelconfirm" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded                  looks like I'm missing a defines in require js, tried some of the things in the link, to add that define, no luck so far. Coming from a java background, js is tough

Comment: Can you update your question with the code from the view model that is attempting to display this modal?

Comment: updated the original question with the contents of the js file, cancel function calls the modal

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you are doing the `require('cancelconfirm')`?

Comment: sorry, that was the version that was working (as long as the view is in the same directory as the viewmodel)
the not loaded yet error occurs when      
app.showModal('areas/share/viewmodels/cancelconfirm').then(function(dialogResult)
is changed to 

var cancelconfirm = require('cancelconfirm');
app.showModal('cancelconfirm').then(function(dialogResult)

Comment: The only thing I can offer is that you have to make sure that the `reuquire('cancelconfirm')` is at the top of the module, **but inside the define block**.  In the code you showed, it should come right after the `var router = require('router')`.  Beyond that it should work, I have code exactly like this that works fine.

Comment: added detail to the original question

Comment: @atl_dev Is the `cancelconfirm` in a folder called cancelconfirm?  In your previous samples that didn't appear to be the case.

Comment: no, the viewmodel and view are called cancelconfirm
areas/share/viewmodels/cancelconfirm.js 
areas/share/views/cancelconfirm.html
 
var cancelconfirm = require('cancelconfirm/cancelconfirm');
The first cancelconfirm above is reference to the cancelconfirm specified in the path in main.js ("areas/share/viewmodels")
and the second cancelconfirm is the file name of the file at that path

Is that not correct?  That is how the other requires are setup (logger, app, etc)

Comment: The only argument you need to pass to requirejs is the name of the viewmodel, so it should be `require('cancelconfirm')` or `require('ares/share/viewmodels/cancelconfirm') depending on how you have your requirejs configured.

Comment: In my define section (in three different flavors)

#1
var cancelconfirm = require('cancelconfirm/cancelconfirm');
** Works =, but only if the view file is in the viewmodel location otherwise;
** Error http://localhost:8085/SkyTrack/resources/areas/share/viewmodels.html 404 (Not Found)

Comment: #2
var cancelconfirm = require('areas/share/viewmodels/cancelconfirm');
** Works =, but only if the view file is in the viewmodel location otherwise;
** Error http://localhost:8085/SkyTrack/resources/areas/share/viewmodels.html 404 (Not Found)

Comment: #3
var cancelconfirm = require('cancelconfirm');
** Error http://localhost:8085/SkyTrack/resources/areas/share/viewmodels.js 404 (Not Found) 
Which would seem like something in the path in main.js, but I don't see it.
It's like it's looking at the path setting   cancelconfirm: "areas/share/viewmodels"  as
the viewmodel file, instead of the directory where the viewmodels are stored.

Comment: In your require.config, you have: `cancelconfirm: "areas/share/viewmodels"`.  That tells require that when you ask for `cancelconfirm`, get it from `areas/share/viewmodels.js`.  Despite the config name `path` here, this is not a directory for it to look in, require looks at this as the specific path and file to load.

Comment: Ok, I see, now it finds the viewmodel.
I changed the cancelconfirm path in main.js to
    cancelconfirm: "areas/share/viewmodels/cancelconfirm" 

and changed the require in the js that calls the modal to
    var cancelconfirm = require('cancelconfirm');

Comment: show modal call remains the same
    var cancel = function() {     
        app.showModal(cancelconfirm).then(function(dialogResult){          
            .......
        });
    };     

It still looks for the view in the viewmodel folder.
Uncaught Error: /resources/areas/share/viewmodels/cancelconfirm.html HTTP status: 404

Comment: sorry, I'm adding four spaces to try to format as code, doesn't seem to take.

Comment: Can you edit your post, or post a gist of your `app.start` code as demonstrated on the getting started (http://durandaljs.com/pages/get-started/) under main.js.

Comment: added ************* Listing of main.js to the original post